# The entity field value is updated after exception throwing and transaction rollback

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-test, hibernate-cache

I have developed a test project to reproduce this issue.

This is a project structure:

[image: The project structure]

pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>value-updated-after-fail-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Persone.java file:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    String name;
}
```

PersonRepository.java file:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

PersonService.java file:

```
@Component
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonRepository repository;

    public PersonService(PersonRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Person create(String name) {
        return repository.save(new Person(name));
    }

    @Transactional
    public Person save(Person person) {
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(person.getName())) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        Person personFromDB = getById(person.getId());
        personFromDB.setName(person.getName());
        return repository.save(personFromDB);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Person getById(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteAll() {
        repository.deleteAll();
    }
}
```

application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

TestApplicationConfiguration.java file

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EntityScan("net.example.model")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.example")
public class TestApplicationConfiguration {}
```

PersonServiceTest.java file:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
class PersonServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService service;

    @AfterEach
    void tearDownEach() {
        service.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void rename() {
        String expected = "name";
        Person person = service.create(expected);
        Person personFromDB = service.getById(person.getId());
        personFromDB.setName("");
        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> service.save(personFromDB));
        assertEquals(expected, service.getById(personFromDB.getId()).getName());
    }
}
```

**The issue:** Last assertion fails

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
Expected :name
Actual   :
```

**What I already tried to fix this?**

1. I tried to remove the `@Transactional` annotation for the PersonService#getById method to avoid getting the entity from the cache. - This didn't fix the issue
2. I tried to add `spring.cache.type=none` to the `application.properties` file to disable the cache. - This didn't fix the issue

**Why do I think it's the cache?**

When I debugged this, I found that the `PersonService#getById()` method doesn't return actual data, but the method returns a cached object with a changed title.
The database isn't changed after calling the `PersonService#save` method because it throws an exception
[image]

Perhaps I'm not developing the tests correctly.
Maybe I should change the method of saving changed data.

Please share best practices and articles to better understand how to update data and how to properly configure and write tests for Spring Boot applications.

Comment: I'm not sure why you believe `person` and `personFromDB` cannot be references to the same object.  The repository is under no obligation to fetch a new copy if it believes its cached copy represents the current state of the database, which in this case it does.

Comment: In this case, the database isn't changed after calling the ```PersonService#save()``` method because an exception is thrown because the title is blank. I expect that when the system calls the ```PersonService#getById()``` method, we should get the actual data since the cached data does not match the data from the database.

Comment: I fixed ```Why do I think it's the cache?``` section of the description

Comment: take a look at `@DataJpaTest` annotation, there is `@Transactional` annotation over class name, that in turn means all your test methods are backed up by a single transaction, that explains why `person` and `perfonFromDB` are the same object instance - HBN picked them up from session level cache (one single transaction - one single session), that is by design.

Comment: to achieve expected result try to inject `TestEntityManager` in test class and call its `.clear()` method before calling methods where you want a DB call - this will force entity manager to detach all managed entities

Comment: @AndrewThomas Your suggestion looks like a workaround

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Thank you very much for your tip, it really helped me to understand my issue and study this topic more deeply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot for [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73575051/the-entity-field-value-is-updated-after-exception-throwing-and-transaction-rollb?noredirect=1#comment129927523_73575051) from [Andrey B. Panfilov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426309/andrey-b-panfilov).

I investigated the `@Transactional` and the first level cache of Hibernate.
Indeed, each test method call in a class annotated with the `@DataJpaTest` annotation creates, runs, and rollbacks a transaction.
Each transaction creates and closes the Hibernate session. As we know, the first level cache exists until the session closes. That's why it's also called session cache.

You can see the evidence in the following screenshots:

[image: Open new session before each test]

In the first screenshot, you can see that `SpringExtension`, which is defined in the `@DataJpaTest` annotation, opens a new session before each test is called.

[image: close the session after each test]

In the second screenshot, you can see that `SpringExtension` closes the session after each test is called.

I decided to override the default transaction propagation:
`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)` it doesn't create a transaction when the method is called and throw an exception if the method is called in an existing transaction

Links that helped me:

1. [Data Access](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#tx-propagation)
2. [Transaction Propagation and Isolation in Spring @Transactional](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation)
3. [Transaction Propagation with illustrations](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-transaction-propagation)
4. [Hibernate Caching - First Level Cach](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/hibernate-caching-first-level-cache)